# Checking if all items in a <select> drop down have a particular class

Tags: jquery

I have a `<select>` drop-down list of item options. If an item is 'out of stock', that `<option>` has a class of 'out-of-stock'.

For example:

```
<select>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue" class="out-of-stock" disabled="disabled">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="yellow" class="out-of-stock" disabled="disabled">Yellow</option>
</select>
<p class="message hidden">Sorry, this item is out of stock</p>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

If **all** options have a class of "out-of-stock", then hide the whole `<select>` drop-down and remove the "hidden" class from the `<p>` element.

I've tried the following, but this hides the whole `<select>` even if just one `<option>` has the class "out-of-stock":

```
$("select").each(function(){
    if ($(this).children("option").hasClass("out-of-stock")) {
        $(this).addClass("hidden");
        $("p.message").removeClass("hidden");
}
});
```

...any ideas how to hide the `<select>` only if **all** items are "out-of-stock"? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says about `hasClass`:

> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

That means it returns `true` if *at least one* of the selected elements has that class, so it is not helpful for this problem.

Instead, you can compare the number of children against those with the class in question:

```
var $children = $(this).children();

if($children.length === $children.filter(".out-of-stock").length) {
   // all elements have this class
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
if ($(this).children("option").hasClass("out-of-stock")) {
```

to this :

```
if ($(this).children("option:not(.out-of-stock)").length == 0) {
```

In short terms you count all the option tags that do not have the class out-of-stock, if the length is 0 that means all the option tags have the class out-of-stock, then you can continue to act acording to it.

Allso you edit `$("p.message").removeClass("hidden");` to `$(this).next().removeClass('hidden')`, so that you show the hidden class only for the select that is out of stock.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with:

```
$("select").each(function() {
    if(!$(this).find("option:not('.out-of-stock')").length) {
        $(this).addClass('hidden').next().removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: Cheers for your help, Interrobang!

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".out-of-stock").length == $("option").length){
        $("select").addClass("hidden");
        $("p.message").removeClass("hidden");
}
```